# when is a response code received during a request for an image using ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, http, protocols

When do I actually get my response code 200 for a valid request for an image?  Is it after all of the data has been downloaded to my browser or which ever device is requesting the image?

I am using the library http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ to download images in my iPad app and using the download directly to a file option and then deleting the file if it was a 404 error or any other status code than 200.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.jpg"];
```

Problem is partial responses seem to be getting saved during slow connections so I end up with blank or corrupt images.

I decided instead to save the data stream to disk only after I received a status code of 200:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [[NSString stringWithFormat:kProductImagesURL, fileName] stringByAppendingString:tStamp]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:10];
[request startSynchronous];

int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
 if (statusCode==200) {
     NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
     [responseData writeToFile:[savePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "] atomically:YES];
    }
```

I just want to make sure that the response code only comes back after the request has been completed and all of the data has been downloaded.  I am 99% sure that is the case but can't afford another app release with an image bug like this in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons you should probably consider switching to an asynchronous request. The first is, it frees up your main thread to interact with the user (even a modal spinner would be nice--otherwise it looks like your app has frozen).

Second, it gives you callbacks that only happen once the whole request is finished. I can't really explain only having gotten partial data with the code you showed, but I've never once had that problem using ASI's asynchronous methods.

Comment: thanks for the input, there is a nice progress bar showing the downloading of the images and I do not want user interaction so no need for me to switch to async at this moment - just really curious as to when the status code comes back - before, during or after the streaming if the image data has occurred.